# Return list of columns with string match in multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrames:

```
d = {'colA': [1, 2], 'colB': [3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to return a list of columns containing the string 'A', e.g. for one DataFrame:

```
[column for column in df.columns if 'A' in column]
```

How can I do this for multiple DataFrames (e.g., df, df2, df3)?

The desired output in this example would be ['colA', 'colA', 'colA']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
l = [','.join(i.columns[i.columns.str.contains('A')]) for i in [df,df2,df3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for that:

```
def find_char(list_of_df , char):
    result = []
    for df in list_of_df:
        for c in df.columns:
            if char in c:
                result.append(c)
    return result
```

Usage:

```
res = find_char([df,df2,df3] , 'A')
print(res)
['colA', 'colA', 'colA']
```